# Sumar objeto donde coincidan las propiedades

Tags: javascript, nodejs, algoritmos

Dados dos objetos  sumar las propiedades que coinciden entre si y agregar las que no estén.

#### obj1

```
obj1 = [
{
   _id:'vehiculo',
   precio:10000
},
{
   _id:'ocio',
   precio:5000
},
]
```

#### obj2

```
obj2 = [
{
   _id:'vehiculo',
   precio:5000
},
{
   _id:'suscripciones',
   precio:100
},
]
```

y espero que el resultado sea

```
rs = [
{
   _id:'vehiculo',
   precio:15000
},
{
   _id:'suscripciones',
   precio:100
},
{
   _id:'ocio',
   precio:5000
},
]
```

intente usando object.keys con un foreach pero no me funciono y otras pruebas que hice no sumaban las claves que no están en el otro objeto.

Lo mas que logro es hacer esto

```
let obj = {};
    ob2.forEach(o2 => {
      ob1.forEach(o1 => {
        o1._id === o2._id && Object.assign(obj,  {[o1._id]:o1.precio+o2.precio})
     })
    })
```

que me devuelve {vehículo:15000} pero no se como hacer para que se agreguen los restantes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí hay dos opciones que se pueden realizar

1. La primera es generar una copia de tu objeto obj1 a tu resultado y adicionarle el segundo objeto, con un ciclo [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) que te recorre todos los ítems en tu array y dentro de cada iteración validar si existe el ítem para acumular o adicionar.

```js
var rs = obj1.map((item) => { return {_id:item._id, precio: item.precio}; });

for (let item of obj2) {
  let itemExistente = rs.find((e) => e._id === item._id )
    if(itemExistente){
    itemExistente.precio += item.precio
  } else {
    rs.push({_id:item._id, precio: item.precio});
  }
}
```

2. La segunda opción es que recorras los dos objetos con el ciclo [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) y que generes la misma validación sobre tu variable resultado, validar si existe para acumular y si no existe para agregar.

```js
var rs = [];
for (let item of obj1) {
  let itemExistente = rs.find((e) => e._id === item._id )
  if(itemExistente){
    itemExistente.precio += item.precio
  } else {
    rs.push({_id:item._id, precio: item.precio});
  }
}
for (let item of obj2) {
  let itemExistente = rs2.find((e) => e._id === item._id )
  if(itemExistente){
    itemExistente.precio += item.precio
  } else {
    rs2.push({_id:item._id, precio: item.precio});
  }
}
```

Este es el ejemplo con los dos tipos de validaciones.

```js
var obj1 = [
  {
     _id:'vehiculo',
     precio:10000
  },
  {
     _id:'ocio',
     precio:5000
  },
]


var obj2 = [
  {
     _id:'vehiculo',
     precio:5000
  },
  {
     _id:'suscripciones',
     precio:100
  },
]

var rs = obj1.map((item) => { return {_id:item._id, precio: item.precio}; });

for (let item of obj2) {
  let itemExistente = rs.find((e) => e._id === item._id )
  if(itemExistente){
    itemExistente.precio += item.precio
  } else {
    rs.push({_id:item._id, precio: item.precio});
  }
}

console.log(rs);

/*Genere la validación en una función adicional, para reducir el codigo*/
var rs2 = [];
for (let item of obj1) {
  acumulaItems(rs2, item);
}
for (let item of obj2) {
  acumulaItems(rs2, item);
}

function acumulaItems(array, item) {
  let itemExistente = array.find((e) => e._id === item._id )
  if(itemExistente){
    itemExistente.precio += item.precio
  } else {
    array.push({_id:item._id, precio: item.precio});
  }
}

console.log(rs2);
```

Comment: gracias use la opcion1. anduvo perfectamente!

Answer (score 1):

Esta puede ser otra forma de resolverlo.

```js
let obj1 = [{
    _id: 'vehiculo',
    precio: 10000
  },
  {
    _id: 'ocio',
    precio: 5000
  },
]

let obj2 = [{
    _id: 'vehiculo',
    precio: 5000
  },
  {
    _id: 'suscripciones',
    precio: 100
  },
]

//Obtenemos solo las claves. 
let claves = [...obj1, ...obj2].map(x => x._id)
//Quitamos repetidos
claves = Array.from(new Set(claves))

//Unimos todos los objetos. 
let todoParaSumarse = [...obj1, ...obj2]
let resultados = []

//Recorremos las claves para crear los nuevos valores. 
claves.forEach(clave => {
  //Sumamos todo lo que coincida con la clave. 
  let sumaPorClave = todoParaSumarse.filter(x => x._id === clave)
    .reduce((pre, cur) => pre + cur.precio, 0)

  //Creamos el nuevo objeto de la clave
  let objeto = {
    _id: clave,
    precio: sumaPorClave
  }
  //Lo agregamos a nuestra pila
  resultados.push(objeto)


})

//Mostramos lo apilado :D
console.log(resultados)
```